# Probability problem from math competition

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

I was training for the math competitions when I've found this problem. I'll try to translate it from italian:

A bad chemist arrives in a lab where 4 groups are working , each consisting of 3 people. Everyone of these people holds a flask with distilled water, each flask with the same amount of water. The bad chemist goes to the first group and puts $a_1$ drops  of sulfuric acid in the first flask, $a_2$ in the second and $a_3$ in the third, so that $a_1+a_2+a_3=4$. In the same way, he goes to the second group and puts $b_1$ drops  of sulfuric acid in the first flask, $b_2$ in the second and $b_3$ in the third, so that $b_1+b_2+b_3=3$. He does the same with the third group, putting $c_1, c_2, c_3$ drops respectively, so that $c_1+c_2+c_3=2$, and with the fourth group, putting $d_1, d_2, d_3$ drops, so that $d_1+d_2+d_3=1$. Assuming that the drops are all of the same size and that the chemist puts the sulfuric acid drops in the flasks randomly, what is the percentage probability that the flask with the most acid solution belongs to the first group (most acid of all the flasks, no ties).

The answer to this problem is $36\%$ (I don't know if it's rounded). I tried to solve the problem in the following way. The possible configurations are:

First group: $4$-$0$-$0$ ($3x$), $3$-$1$-$0$ ($6x$), 2-2-0 (3x), 2-1-1 (3x) -> 15 configurations

Second group: $3$-$0$-$0$ ($3x$), $2$-$1$-$0$ ($6x$), 1-1-1 (1x) -> 10 configurations

Third group: $2$-$0$-$0$ ($3x$), $1$-$1$-$0$ ($3x$) -> 6 configurations

Fourth group: $1$-$0$-$0$ ($3x$) -> 3 configurations

Thus, all the possible configurations are $15\cdot 10\cdot 6\cdot 3=2700$. The "good" ones are:

$4$-$0$-$0$ for the first group:  all of the second, third, fourth group configurations are "good"-> $3\cdot 10\cdot 6\cdot 3=540$

$3$-$1$-$0$ for the first group:  2-1-0 and 1-1-1 of the second group, all of the third and fourth are "good" -> $6\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 3=756$

$2$-$1$-$1$ for the first group:  1-1-1 of the second group, 1-1-0 of the third, all of the fourth are "good"-> $3\times 1\times 3 \times 3=27$

$2$-$2$-$1$ for the first group:  no configurations, because we have a tie

The probability become $$\dfrac{540+756+27}{2700}=0,49=49\%$$
I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Not sure the problem is clear:  are we assured in advance that there is a *unique* max or is this part of the event we are meant to compute the probability of?  Surely we aren't meant to assume that there are no duplicates at all, right?

Comment: Actually, the phrasing of the problem is very confusing.  What does "randomly" mean here?  What is the exact process used, and what are the underlying probability distributions?

Comment: The outcomes counted by stars-and-bars are very often not equally likely to occur.  That is to say, the outcome where the chemist adds four drops to the first and none to the rest is in most problems not going to be equally likely to occur as the outcome where the chemist puts two drops in the first, one drop in the second, and one drop in the third.  Now... it might be possible that in your problem you are to assume those are equally likely... but again, in most problems they are not equally likely.

Comment: A reasonable approach the chemist could (*or should*) take is to have the three flasks in front of him... pick one of the three uniformly at random to put the first drop in... then again uniformly at random and independently of the first choice make a choice as to which to put the second drop in... and so on... This leads to $3^4=81$ different equally likely sequences of where the drops are placed in the first set of flasks... far more than the $15$ you counted.  While you could organize those 81 outcomes into the 15 different categories you refer to, those 15 categories aren't equally likely.

Comment: @JMoravitz I solved this problem using the reasonable approach you discuss in your last comment and I'm getting an answer of $\frac{97}{243}$ which is about $40$%. Are you able to confirm this numerical value?

Comment: @lulu The problem asks the percentage probability that the flask with the most acid solution belongs only to the first group. The cases in which there are more max are not included in the probability we want.

Comment: That does not answer any of my questions.  As it stands, "solving" this problem requires someone to supply all the missing information and assumptions.  Reasonable people will guess differently as to those and the different starting points will inevitably lead to different results.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for your answer, I think you could be right. I'll try to solve the problem again, following your suggestion.

Comment: @lulu The text says "a caso", which means randomly. There are no further explanations. I think that means an uniform distribution.

Comment: "Uniform distribution" on what?  One way to make sense out of the problem would be to say something like "the chemist uniformly at random selects a number of drops from $\{0,1,2\}$ and when it is all done it is noticed that the number of drops follows the pattern described.  Then..."  But this is so far from what is actually written than I would be surprised to learn that I guessed the intent correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @JMoravitz, I solved the problem. The mistake in my first solution was that I considered all the "configurations" equally likely to occur. Like suggested, you have to put attention also to the order of placing the drops in the set of flasks. Doing that, all the possible configuarations are:

First group: 4-0-0 (3x), 3-1-0 (24x), 2-2-0 (18x), 2-1-1 (36x) -> $3^4=81$ configurations

Second group: 3-0-0 (3x), 2-1-0 (18x), 1-1-1 (6x) -> $3^3=27$ configurations

Third group: 2-0-0 (3x), 1-1-0 (6x) -> $3^2=9$ configurations

Fourth group: 1-0-0 (3x) -> $3$ configurations

Thus, all the possible configurations are $3^4\cdot 3^3\cdot 3^2\cdot 3= 3^{10}=59049$. The "good" ones are:

4-0-0 for the first group: all of the second, third, fourth group configurations are "good"-> $3\cdot 27\cdot 9\cdot 3=2187$

3-1-0 for the first group: 2-1-0 and 1-1-1 of the second group, all of the third and fourth are "good"-> $24\cdot 24\cdot 9\cdot 3=15552$

2-1-1 for the first group: 1-1-1 of the second group, 1-1-0 of the third, all of the fourth are "good"-> $36\times 6\times 6 \times 3=3888$

2-2-1 for the first group: no configurations, because we have a tie

The probability become $$\dfrac{2187+15552+3888}{59049}=\dfrac{21627}{59049}=\dfrac{89}{243}\approx 36\%$$
Thank you all again.